# TFS 2010 Automated Deployment Process

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, continuous-integration, build-automation

I am trying to understand the automated deployment process in TFS 2010.

I have a DEV, QA, Stage, and Live environments.  Using a basic (or standard branching strategy), when configuring automatic builds/deployments does deploying to DEV get code from the MAIN branch to the DEV Server.  Then if I want code to go to QA, do the bits on the DEV Server go to QA Server?  Then get bits from QA Server to Stage?  And finally from Stage to Live?  So once code goes from TFS to DEV it's just a matter of moving source code from each Server to the next?

Or is it typical to grab code from DEV branch (instead of MAIN branch) to go to DEV Server and then move code to each Server as described above?

Just trying to understand the automated deployment process and what is a standard configuration.

Thanks for any info given...

Comment: What kind of projects?  Web? DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The goal of deployment is to send a branch's code to an environment.

So, if you are working in the MAIN branch and choose to deploy to DEV, the code from that MAIN branch would get deployed (copied, installed, et al) to whatever is configured as the DEV environment.

Most people do not have one branch per environment. You probably would have a DEV branch separate from the MAIN branch, but that's a source control management concern separate from automated deployment. You might want to retag this question along those lines.

Comment: I think we're saying the same thing here, and I think your answer is better worded. I concur that as far as deployment is concerned, the branch is only involved as the source of the "package" that's being deployed.

Answer (score 3):

TFS does not have a single built-in automated deployment process. You need to specify how and where your code will be deployed, depending on the type of project.

Deployment is about deploying the results of a successful build. Deployment is about branches only to the extent that you have built a branch.